# How to embed a GitHub gist in the Angular template?

Tags: javascript, angular, github, embedding, gist

Angular ignores `script` tags in its template, but they are required to load GitHub gist. What is the best practice to do this? Using `iframe`? Creating `script` tag dynamically? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to create an `iframe` with `script` inside and append it whenever you want your gist to appear (based on [jasonhodges](https://github.com/jasonhodges/ngx-gist/blob/master/lib/ngx-gist.ts) solution).

### Template

```
 <iframe #iframe type="text/javascript"></iframe>
```

### Component

```
@ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

gistUrl: string;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentElement.contentWindow;
    const content = `
        <html>
        <head>
          <base target="_parent">
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="${this.gistUrl}"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
    `;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(content);
    doc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [angular-gist](https://github.com/scottcorgan/angular-gist) or [ngx-gist](https://github.com/jasonhodges/ngx-gist) to embed GitHub gists.

## angular-gist:

Install:

```
npm install angular-gist --save
```

Usage as module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['gist']);
```

Usage as directive:

```
<gist id="1234556"></gist>
```

## ngx-gist:

Install:

```
npm i --save ngx-gist
```

Usage:

```
import { NgxGistModule } from 'ngx-gist/dist/ngx-gist.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        NgxGistModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

## for your own implementation:

[**check out how you can use an iframe for this**](https://github.com/jasonhodges/ngx-gist/blob/master/lib/ngx-gist.ts)

Comment: "AngularJS directive for embedding Github gists." I need a solution for Angular 2+ preferably with no redundant dependencies.

Comment: Then check out the sources of these repositories. [They use an iframe.](https://github.com/jasonhodges/ngx-gist/blob/master/lib/ngx-gist.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I used [angular-gist-embed](https://github.com/pasupulaphani/angular-gist-embed) several times now using Bower to achieve this.

- Just install it like: `bower install angular-gist-embed`
- Then add it: `angular.module('myModule',['gist-embed'])`

And I use the particular GitHub Gist's id to embed it:

```
<code data-gist-id="5457595"></code>
```

You can find more examples [here](http://blairvanderhoof.com/gist-embed/).